# Making iPhone ready for development - XCode 12

Tags: ios, xcode

I have been waiting from days now, and the xCode is still hung with the message "Making iPhone ready for development".

I have tried:

- Waited for days
- Disconnect phone, restarting xCode
- Rebooting phone.
- Rebooting mac

versions:

```
xCode 12.0
2017 macbook pro - OS Version 12.3.1 - Intel Core i5
iPhone 7 plus - iOS 15.7
```

Comment: How is Xcode 12 supposed to cope with a device running iOS 15? The whole question makes no sense. Update to Xcode 14.0.1.

Answer (score 0):

Xcode 12.0 is not compatible with iOS versions 14.1 or later. In order to support iOS 15.5-15.7, you need to upgrade to Xcode 13.4 or later.